# Best Gui editors used in linux for the handeling database(oracle,mysql)?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, user-interface, editor

toad works fine in windows but we need wine to install it in linux. is there any other software equivalent to that for the linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html). They have a Linux download available and it is just Java, I think. It is unclear exactly how much support it provides for MySQL but there is definitely some support.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

@work we were recently looking for a replacement for Toad - we looked at sql developer, tora and squirrel. Nobody was very impressed with Squirrel. Tora was a simple system, easy to use, but we settled on SQLDeveloper due to the additional functionality there.